# Working with ColdFusion - Looping a procedure

Tags: coldfusion, sybase

I'm wondering if there is a better way to do what I'm doing. It works but I feel there should be a better way. If my query result in 20K records for example, I'm getting "The request has exceeded the allowable time limit Tag: CFQUERY"

```
            <cfquery name="GetMyRecords" datasource="MyDSN">
              SELECT idnumber,PrefAddr,...more colums
              FROM um_valid
              WHERE userid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"
                                         value="#session.userid#">
              AND session_id = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_numeric" 
                                         value="#session.Session_Id#">
              AND status NOT IN (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 

              value="X,C">)
            </cfquery>
```

I also have an existing store procedure that expect some values from the query to do what it's supposed to do. So I'm looping it like this:

```
<cfloop query="GetMyRecords">
   <cfstoredproc procedure="MyProc" datasource="MyDSN">
      <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" 
                       dbvarname="@id_number" value="#Trim(idnumber)#">
      <cfprocparam type="In" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" 
                    dbvarname="@Aaddr_pref_ind" value="#Trim(PrefAddr)#">
      ----- still more params to be passed----
   </cfstoredproc>
</cfloop>
```

Does ColdFusion has a better technique to avoid either time out error or 500 error?

Comment: I suggest modifying your stored procedure or writing a new one so that you don't have to make any database calls inside that loop.

Comment: How if I create a function inside a existing component and call the function on every loop? is that going to help?

Comment: You can try, but I doubt it.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the stored procedure? Perhaps it is possible to dump it completely and only run just one query (perhaps with an additional cffuntion). Running 20k queries is always slow because no matter what you do it will always take several milliseconds to run a query (eg 20 milliseconds per query * 20.000 queries = 400 seconds = 6.6 minutes). If this is not an issue you can always follow luxdvie advice and just increase the requestTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

Like another poster mentioned, reducing the number of database calls should be a priority to you. I suggest joining data (if possible) in your first query rather than looping your query and querying again.

To fix the time issue, you can put [requestTimeout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d68.html) in your page to override the default timeout. The time is in seconds.

```
<cfsetting requestTimeOut = "600">
```

[See this explanation.](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-mx-explanation-request-timeout.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your current approach is to make `1` query, which contains `n` records. Then loop over that record set, calling a query for each record. This results in your calling `n + 1` queries per request. As the volume of data returned by your first query increases, so too does the volume of overall queries made to the database. In your case, you're trying to make `20,001` calls to the database in a single request.

Ideally, you need a solution that involves one call to a stored procedure with a properly optimized query that can return all of your data in a single record set. If you don't need to dump all the data onto the page at the same time, then create a paginated query that will return `x` number of records per page. Then the user can go page by page through the query or provide a search form with additional filters to allow the user to reduce the overall size of the records returned.

Answer (score 0):

Need to see full queries to give you an example, but in general, this is a really useful thing in CF to help you out!

You need to look into the  attribute called group.  This lets you specify a column to group your output by.  This actually will eliminate the need for the stored proc you are calling entirely.

The way it works is letting you create sub-set outputs based on grouping.  So for example, you could do this with your id's and output that group.

You can also have multiple of these and have header and footer sections for each one for display purposes or just logic manipulation.

This lets you query the entire dataset and then manipulate it in the loop without having subqueries which is ultra inefficient and cringe worthy.

This is something quite unique to ColdFusion, check it out!

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7ff6.html